# How to add strings from lists to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary

So I currently have a list of strings:

```
name_row = ['Bob', 'Jerry', 'Will']
rating_row = ['4.0', '2.5', '3.7']
title_row = ['Geat', 'Okay', 'Nice']
```

and my desired result is something like this:

| Names | Rating | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 4.0 | Great |
| Jerry | 2.5 | Okay |
| Will | 3.7 | Nice |

What I have so far is

```
rows = []
row = {}

name_row = ['Bob', 'Jerry', 'Will']
rating_row = ['4.0', '2.5', '3.7']
title_row = ['Geat', 'Okay', 'Nice']
        
for name in name_row:
    row['Name'] = row.get(name)

rows.append(row)

df = (pd.DataFrame(rows))
```

but I'm getting {'Name':none} when I call df and I don't know how to add those strings from the lists to a dictionary?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': name_row, 'Rating': rating_row, 'Title': title_row})`?

Comment: Your desired output is `{'Bob': {'rating_row': '4.0', 'title_row': 'Great'}, 'Jerry': {'rating_row': '2.5', 'title_row': 'Okay'}, 'Will': {'rating_row': '3.7', 'title_row': 'Nice'}}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': name_row, 'Rating': rating_row, 'Title': title_row})
print(df)
#    Names Rating Title
# 0    Bob    4.0  Geat
# 1  Jerry    2.5  Okay
# 2   Will    3.7  Nice
```

This construction is explained in the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). In particular, read the first example therein:

```py
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# df
#    col1  col2
# 0     1     3
# 1     2     4
```

Answer (score 2):

So, your first issue is that there's nothing in row, so when you call

```
row.get(name)
```

there's nothing there to get. Hence the {'Name':none} output.

If you already have the 3 rows to work with, the easiest way to get your desired result is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': name_row, 'Rating': rating_row, 'Title': title_row})
```

Using the DataFrame() method with these parameters sets the column names to 'Names','Rating', and 'Title'. Each column name becomes the key in a dictionary, where the value for each key becomes your existing lists of strings. Now, your dataframe is a dictionary of [String: List of String]